# Version control for video editing work

Tags: version-control, video, image

I am looking into improving the backup process a group of animators use. Currently they back up their work into external hard drives or DVDs manually, taking full copies of everything. The data consists of thousands of high resolution images, project files of various video editing software and sound files. Basically everything is binary data and nothing should ever be merged on checkin.

Should I investigate version control systems that I would use as a software developer (Subversion, GIT etc.), or is there a class of version control systems intended for non-SW data that would suit these needs better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your scope is just "backup" then I'd say stick to backup solutions.

But if you are thinking about the whole lifecycle of the animator's work, then the type of use typically falls into the ["Digital Asset Management"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management) category for the very reasons you mention: huge data volumes; binary formats.

Since [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) (SCM) software is usually designed for text files that can be diff'd and merged, they tend not to do so well with binary formats in high volume. While your average web graphics are not going to be an issue for (software) version control tools, you mention video, which puts you in another league.

The bad news (maybe - depends on your business) is that DAM is dominated by the big end of town. @Atmospherian has mentioned [AlienBrain](http://www.softimage.com/products/alienbrain/) which is a good representative of niche offering for artists. At the other end of the spectrum you have more general purpose offerings like [Oracle's UCM](http://www.oracle.com/products/middleware/content-management/digital-asset-management.html) (formerly Stellent). Make sure you check the price tags though.

There must be open source or lower cost alternatives available - but I don't know them, sorry.

What does seem to be very common are custom inhouse solutions. Unlike managing code, where changes to the files themselves have their own significance, managing digital assets tends to focus on the metadata (the image/video is just an associated blob). And since since many shops have their own particular production workflow, it makes the territory ripe for some skunkworks programming (if that's your bent - go for it!).

So while I'm not recommending any particular products, I suggest if you think "digital asset management" rather than "version control" when scouting for solutions you will probably find answers more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You could also check out [AlienBrain](http://www.softimage.com/products/alienbrain/). Its a project asset management system designed for artists.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear - you seem to have conflated version control and backup.

If what you want is version control, then take a look at the list on wikipedia: [Comparison of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software). That shows most of the widely known version control systems, and their basic features. You're looking for something where you can set it up to force user's to checkout before they edit. Be aware that commercial solutions range in price from moderately expensive up to 'You want HOW much?'

If what you want is backup software, then I'd start at [List of backup software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) in wikipedia. There's a lot more choices in the backup software arena, and there are a lot of price points.

Either way, figure in the creation of a admin position (either as part of someone's job or a new person altogether, if you're big enough). I've worked with backup and version control systems that didn't have an admin and it's a problem. Either no one takes care of problems, or everyone gets their fingers in there and really screws things up. Either way, making it part of someone's job (officially) is the best way to limit damage.

Answer (score 0):

I think Clearcase would work for you.The reason being everything is VOB(VersionedObject) no matter what it is ! Check once

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you would do pretty well with some basic backup software such as [Retrospect](http://www.emcinsignia.com/products/). Using daily backups of workstations, only changed data would be backed up and it would be easy to roll back to an earlier version of a file if needed.

What you don't get from such a setup is the ability to check out / check in files and get warnings about conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Vidyatel has an editing software that can compere video content and find the difference between the video versions leaning on the video only. 
The result is in - EDL/TC.

It might help.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [boar](http://code.google.com/p/boar/). It is exactly what you want, "version control and backup for photos, videos and other binary files". It is version control designed for large binary files.